# setInterval in Angular JS for HighCharts-ng does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, timer

How do i set setInterval in angularjs highcharts ng line chart config settings. I am working on creating a dynamic line chart using highcharts-ng and my chart displays the initial static data and when it comes to displaying dynamic data i see that load event in scope.chartConfig4 does not get attention so my chart remains static. Here is my code snippet.

**Update:** I am using highcharts-ng an angular directive which does not display my dynamic map even after i corrected the timeout to interval. I am trying to convert the following code http://www.tutorialspoint.com/highcharts/highcharts_dynamic_spline.htm using angularjs . Please help.

```js
 $scope.chartConfig4 = {
   chart: {
     type: 'spline',
     animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
     marginRight: 10,
     events: {
       load: function() {

         // set up the updating of the chart each second
         var series = this.series[0];
         setInterval(function() {
           var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
             y = Math.random();
           series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
         }, 1000);
       }
     }
   },
   title: {
     text: ''
   },
   xAxis: {
     type: 'datetime',
     tickPixelInterval: 150
   },
   yAxis: {
     title: {
       text: 'Users(in thousands)'
     },
     plotLines: [{
       value: 0,
       width: 1,
       color: '#808080'
     }]
   },
   tooltip: {
     formatter: function() {
       return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
         Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
         Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
     }
   },
   legend: {
     enabled: false
   },
   exporting: {
     enabled: false
   },
   series: [{
     name: 'Users',
     data: (function() {
       // generate an array of random data
       var data = [],
         time = (new Date()).getTime(),
         i;

       for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
         data.push({
           x: time + i * 1000,
           y: Math.random()
         });
       }
       return data;
     }())
   }]
 };
```

**Update:**  I am using highcharts-ng an angular directive which does not display my dynamic map even after i corrected the timeout to interval. I am trying to convert the following code http://www.tutorialspoint.com/highcharts/highcharts_dynamic_spline.htm using angularjs . Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setInterval takes you outside of Angular's scope, meaning that `$scope.apply()` is never called.  You should use [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) instead so that a digest cycle is properly triggered.

```
$interval(function() {
    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
    y = Math.random();
    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks David!. I am using highcharts-ng an angular directive which does not display my dynamic map even after i corrected the timeout to interval. I am trying to convert the following code http://www.tutorialspoint.com/highcharts/highcharts_dynamic_spline.htm using angularjs . Please help.

Comment: @John it is too difficult to troubleshoot a library I'm not familiar with when you aren't able to narrow down the exact issue.  Are you able to create a plunker or a jsfiddle that reproduces the issue?